# RibbonApplicationMenu left to right instead of below each other

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, caliburn.micro, ribbon

We are using `Caliburn Micro` in our C# WPF app and we have this pretty standard `RibbonApplicationMenuView.xaml`:

```
<RibbonApplicationMenu x:Class="NatWa.MidOffice.Modules.Shared.Ribbon.RibbonApplicationMenuView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:NatWa.MidOffice.Modules.Shared.Ribbon"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData RibbonApplicationMenuViewModel}" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <RibbonApplicationMenu.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SourceItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.Source>
                <ribbon:ViewCollection Source="{Binding Items}"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.Source>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </RibbonApplicationMenu.Resources>

    <RibbonApplicationMenu.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource SourceItems}"/>
    </RibbonApplicationMenu.ItemsSource>

</RibbonApplicationMenu>
```

With the `RibbonApplicationMeuViewModel.cs`:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace NatWa.MidOffice.Modules.Shared.Ribbon
{
    public class RibbonApplicationMenuViewModel : PropertyChangedBase 
    {
        private BindableCollection<RibbonItem> _items;

        public RibbonApplicationMenuViewModel()
        {
            Items = new BindableCollection<RibbonItem>();
        }

        public BindableCollection<RibbonItem> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _items)) return;
                _items = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the items are being added like so:

```
private static RibbonApplicationMenuViewModel CreateApplicationMenu(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    var menu = new RibbonApplicationMenuViewModel();
    menu.Items.Add(new RibbonApplicationMenuItemViewModel<ExitCommand>(i18n.Afsluiten, eventAggregator));
    menu.Items.Add(new RibbonApplicationMenuItemViewModel<CheatSheetCommand>(i18n.CheatSheet, eventAggregator));
    return menu;
}
```

This results in the following menu:
[image]

What I want instead however, is to have these two items next to each other, like with the following MS Paint modificaton I've made:
[image]

Does anyone know what `Property` I should use on the `RibbonApplicationMenu`, or what I should add in a custom `Style`? I looked through the RibbonApplicationMenu properties and couldn't find anything obvious I should use for this (unless I overlooked it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
<RibbonTab> 
<RibbonGroup>
<RibbonMenuItem>

</RibbonMenuItem>
</RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

for arranging it in the Horizontal way. Adding items directly might not give your expected result

Comment: That does indeed make sense. But which properties should I add/modify in which of these you mentioned, in order to make them Horizontally?